# Deploying exe files along with a Silverlight application

Tags: wpf, silverlight, deployment, browser, installation

We have a WPF application that we want to convert to Silverlight. I understand there are going to challenges in converting the application. We are willing to embrace those challenges as long as it is possible for us to accomplish the end goal.

Our WPF application launches some exe (non-WPF) files. So the question is, can we deploy those files with our Silverlight application? If so, can we still run the application from a browser?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these other exes do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can run exe on client machine from silverlight so there is no point of embedding them into xap.

Maybe you can think about multi-targeting your code so you will have one code-base for wpf and silverlight.

Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee321573.aspx) article.